# Cookies PHP sendo encerrados dentro do limite de tempo

Tags: php, pdo

Olá, boa noite
Eu gostaria muito que alguém me tirasse uma dúvida sobre cookies em PHP
quando eu seto o cookie ele vai normalmente para a área de cookies do navegador com a data correta para qual eu configurei, que nesse caso é uma data de expiração de 5 anos. Porém quando eu fecho o navegador o cookie simplesmente desaparece como se nunca tivesse existido. E isso acontece com qualquer navegador que eu faça o teste. Tem alguma coisa que eu possa fazer pra corrigir isso?

Segue a parte do meu código que configura os cookies

```
if(isset($_POST['remember-login']) or $_POST['remember-login']=="1")
                {
                  $time = time()+3600*24*30*12*5;
                  //echo"<script> alert('".$time."'); </script>";
                  //session_set_cookie_params($time);
                  setcookie("token_session", sha1($user['id']), time()+3600*24*30*12*5);
                  //$token_session = $_COOKIE["token_session"];
                  $_SESSION['token_session'] = $_COOKIE["token_session"];
                  $token_session = $_SESSION['token_session'];
                  echo"<script> window.location.href='redireciona.php' </script>";
                }else{
                  setcookie("token_session", sha1($user['id']));
                  //$token_session = $_COOKIE["token_session"];
                  $_SESSION['token_session'] = $_COOKIE["token_session"];
                  $token_session = $_SESSION['token_session'];
                  echo"<script> window.location.href='redireciona.php' </script>";
                }
```

Comment: Esse é o tipo de problema que não dá para ser reproduzido. Tentei reproduzi-lo e não consegui... Esse problema aconteceu comigo a quase 5 anos atrás, eu resolvi  fazendo isso: `setcookie("token_session", sha1($user['id']), time()+3600*24*30*12*5, "/");` .... não sei se vai resolver para você...

Comment: Parece que resolveu aqui cara, muito obrigado mano, eu não tinha idéia de como iria resolver essa questão, até pensei que fosse problema do servidor. Vlw mesmo

Comment: Tranquilo... =)